# User permissions per directory in static cloud storage based website

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

My issue is that I want to host my website in a bucket on either Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage. In my website, each user has his/her own directory that they should have read/write permissions to. But I don't want each user to have read/write permissions to the entire website or any of the other user's directories. 
I can think of 3 possible solutions:

1.)  I have a separate bucket for each user for which they have read/write permissions. I am trying to find a way to redirect the directories in the website bucket to the user's buckets. Would it work to just redirect the index.html page in the user's directory to their personal bucket?

2.) I have a single bucket for the entire website and I set an ACL entry for each user's directory to given them read/write permissions to only their directory. The issue is that I don't think it is possible to set ACLs for directories, only for entire buckets or individual objects.

3.) I use separate git repos for each user's directory then manually and periodically (with a script) fetch all user's most recent changes from their git repositories and update the source in the website bucket myself.

I really want to avoid option 3 if possible. So my question is: Is there a way to give user's read/write permissions to only their own directories within a website that is hosted on a cloud storage bucket?

Comment: So... it's a static site that has no back-end application server?  How (in scenario 1 or 2) will each user actually upload their content? That will be one factor that determines how you might accomplish it.  Or, with option 3, using github web hooks to publish the content in near real time seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: ...or even use github web pages to host the site behind AWS CloudFront, which allows requests to be forwarded to a different back-end target for each path prefix, while consolidating all the content under a single hostname that points to CloudFront would also work, if there are less than 25 users.

Comment: In scenario 1 or 2, the user's would upload their content to the website by logging onto Google Cloud Platform or Amazon S3 with their account (each user would be required to have an account) then navigating into the appropriate bucket and uploading their content. It seems like the most straight forward for users to update their directories on the website.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot limit the number of users to 25. Is that a limitation of CloudFront? I'm also not very familiar with github webhooks. Do you think that this can be done with a single github repository? For example, I have a single git repo that only allows user's to push to specific directories. And when a commit is pushed to the repo the changes are pushed to the bucket that is configured as a static website? Thanks for the ideas :)

Comment: *each user would be required to have an account* S3 is not going to work that way.  I can grant you permission to upload into my bucket through the API with credentials from your AWS account, but you wouldn't see my bucket in your console. GCS, I'm not as sure, but such a solution seems awkward and unweildy.  25 distinct path patterns is the default limit, but you can submit a (free) support request describing your use case and this limit can be increased. I don't know what the hard limit is, but this is a very slick solution for combining disparate resources under a single hostname.

Comment: Hmmm ok so the CloudFront idea is indeed pretty cool. With this idea I would have to make a separate bucket for each user, grant read/write permissions to the user for their bucket and then tell CloudFront the path prefix that corresponds to that bucket. I need to make it as easy as possible to add/remove users. Do you think an adequate solution can be achieved with a single git repo and using webhooks?

Comment: Assuming github allows you to control permission at a directory level, I don't see why not.  You'll need code running somewhere to receive the events, pull, and push changes to S3, but conceptually it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scenario #1 on Google Cloud Storage, you can try out [Google Cloud Load Balancer's support for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage), currently in Alpha. You would have individual buckets per user with the right ACLs for that user, and then create URL map entries for each user pointing to their bucket.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea when this feature might come out of Alpha? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't believe there's a publicly-committed date yet; stay tuned.